# filter_var(): is this a valid URL?

Tags: php

I have the following:

```
$url= "http://t";

if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
    echo "FALSE";
} else {
    echo "TRUE";
}
```

This is returning true, when it's not a valid website. Why?

Comment: As `t` could be a hostname this is perfectly valid.

Comment: What do you mean "not a valid website"?  Are you thinking that `t` is not a valid hostname?  It is.  Are you expecting that filter_var() checks the existence of the site?  It doesn't.

Comment: Some more info: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Validating-URL-Protocols-Hosts-and-Paths-with-Filters-in-PHP-5/2/

Comment: filter_var("ht:/2**(2.commmy", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) is also valid. This cannot be valid.

Answer (score 8):

`http://t` is a valid URL, just like:

```
http://localhost
```

See here:

http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

Comment: I am also running websites on a local webserver which I can reach as for example `http://crm5`. It works.

Comment: Because it is syntactically correct. You should check if it exists using curl for example.

Comment: @Walter Because `t.` is a valid hostname. [Here's a `ping` result](http://pastebin.com/zrBzMzfP) after I've added it to `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: Well, it's more like "t" is a valid hostname and the [trailing dot is a way of terminating an FQDN](http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html), that's not normally bothered with outside of zone files. But the point stands: http://t. is a perfectly valid URL that could point to a machine called t.